# wordpress　Simple Membership　プラグインエラー

Tags: wordpress

#### 前提・実現したいこと

wordpressでSimple Membershipプラグインを使用してます。
最近、3人が登録しました。そのうちの1人は、支払い後に登録を完了することができました。
他の2人は課金してるのにログインして会員ページに行っても「おっと！そのページが見つかりません」
というメッセージが表示されます。
通常はユーザー名がでるのですがユーザー名が　Incomplete membership　となります。
こうなると会員ページに飛ばずエラーぺージに飛びます。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

Incomplete membership

Comment: [debugモード](https://simple-membership-plugin.com/enable-debug-logging/)があるようです。それを有効化して同様の動作をしてログ等になにか重要な情報は載っていませんか？

Comment: 通常の場合デバッグモードがあるのですが私のには無いのです
このためエラーログを取ることができません

Comment: なぜないのでしょうか？もしかしたらそこに原因のヒントがありそうですね。利用しているWordPressのバージョンやプラグインのバージョンまた環境の情報どのようにプラグインを入れたのかも合わせて記載してみてください。

Comment: カスタマイズされたサイトを購入したからだと思います。
違うサーバにSimple Membershipを入れて比較して気づきました。
WordPressのバージョン
カスタマイズされたサイトを購入したからだと思います。
違うサーバにSimple Membershipを入れて比較して気づきました。
WordPressのバージョン 5.5
プラグインのバージョン バージョン 3.9.1

Comment: カスタマイズされていることやバージョンの情報はコメントではなく[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/72831/edit)で質問に追記しましょう。古くなったコメントは[消される可能性](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)があります。またカスタマイズした方にどうゆう導入をしたのかヒアリングすることは難しいですか？まずは再現性をとらない現象の把握が難しいでしょう。